# I want my modPath variables to be from one directory

Tags: directory

I want my modPath variables to be from one directory, is the following correct? Using C#. Thank you ^^

```
private readonly string modPath = @"C:\Users\SusanPeter\Mods";

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(modPath))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry wrong directory");
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to get files from a directory?

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginning, learning to Write a program to check whether this particular Path (C:\Users\SusanPeter\Mods) is valid, and as long as not empty.

If this program is not placed in (C:\Users\SusanPeter\Mods), it will prompt for a message. I am sort of ensuring the path is correct before starting the program.